# How to increment an array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, post, while-loop

I am trying to post the contents of an array to a MySQL database using PHP.

```
$i = 0;

while($i < 8 ) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO posted (posty) 
VALUES ('$nummARAY[1]')");

$i = $i +1;
}
```

But I would like `$nummARAY` to count up by 1 each loop (until it gets to 8 of course)

I am sure this is super newbie stuff, so hopefully there is a one or two word answer out there.

Thanks, Will!

Comment: You shouldn't do 8 separate queries. You can insert multiple rows into a table with one query. You also shouldn't use `mysql_query`. It's been deprecated for many reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`$nummARAY[$i]` instead of `$nummARAY[1]`.

(if the first index of `$numARAY` should be 0).

**More details**

If `$numARAY`'s first index should be 1, just move the `$i = $i +1` line to the beginning of the loop, so it looks like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 8 ) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO posted (posty) 
    VALUES ('$nummARAY[$i]')");
    }
```

Also, you can substitute the `$i = $i + 1` line with more concise `$++`. See [incrementing/decrementing operators in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

In fact, as Paulpro commented, you're better of with a single MySQL query. It's quite easy to do. For example (from a [good tutorial](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/)):

```
INSERT INTO example
    (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
    (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
    (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
    (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
    (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```